# why I can not get double value in java?

Tags: java, variables

I have a problem. My output is:

> 8.7E7

I want to set it to 87000000.
What should I do?

```
public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double num = 87000000;

        System.out.println("num = " + num);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
System.out.printf("num = %.0f", num);
```

This will print the double value with zero decimal places.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html for details on the formatting in `printf`.

If you want to use the String somewhere then use:

```
    String msg = String.format("num = %.0f", num);
```

Comment: And then I want to output in Toast like

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

printf cannot use in it

Comment: @AhmadBudiU Added info about `String.format`

Comment: Thanks sir, that's work (y)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     double num = 87000000;

     System.out.printf("num = %.0f \n", num);
}}
```

Just change your System.out.println() to System.out.printf() and use the format specifier. The "\n” adds a new line.

For more details on how that works, just visit this link.

http://www.alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet